# Generic Extension on non Generic Class?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following class which represents a custom array structure:

```
class MyArrayClass {
...
}
```

Now I want to create an extension on this class to make it type save. I would like to do something like this:

```
extension MyArrayClass<T> {

    func getAtIndex(i:Int) -> T {
        return self.getAtIndex(i) as! T
    }

}
```

**Is it possible to extend a class with a generic parameter?**

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't extend a class so as to change it from nongeneric to generic or vice versa. However, it is hard to see why you didn't just make this class generic to start with. In other words, instead of trying to this with an extension, do it with your original class declaration.

Alternatively, you can make *individual methods* of your nongeneric class generic. For example, `getAtIndex` could be generic even if MyArrayClass is not.

However, guessing what sort of thing you're probably up to, I think a generic MyArrayClass is going to make the most sense.

Comment: Because I do not have access to the original class.

Comment: Yes, I secretly knew that was the reason. :)